# Display a text inside a div in html using a variable from an external php file

Tags: php, html

I want to display a text in a div in html. So usually I can do this as below.

```
<div class = "profileText" style = "margin-top: 5%;">Hello</div> <br>
```

What I want to do is to display text using a variable from another php file.
Like I have these variables in a php file named profileLoad.php

```
<?php
   $firstname = "Arnab";
   $lastname = "Das";
?>
```

I can't figure it out and I am a beginner in php/html/css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `include/require` function to include php file at the begining of the html file.
Then simply echo `$firstname.''.$lastname;`

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the `include/require` functions. They are intended for loading external resources.

So just add an include at the top of your page, and your variables will be imported into your main page, and will be accessible.

Comment: But what do I have to write inside the div to display the text in that variable?

Comment: you can use the builtin `echo` function to output any text or variable with php. Simply do `<div><?php echo $someVariable; ?></div>`
These really are the basics of php... You may want to follow some tutorial to get a grip on things.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, if this is what you were looking for?

```
   <?php
       $firstname = "Arnab";
       $lastname = "Das";
    ?>

<div class = "profileText" style = "margin-top: 5%;"><?php echo $firstname.' '.$lastname;?></div> <br>
```

Comment: I have found solution. Thanks for giving your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , make sure that you have two .php files, for example : Main.php & profileLoad.php .

**Main.php**

```
<?php include("profileLoad.php");?>
<html><head></head><body>
 <div class = "profileText" style = "margin-top: 5%;"><?php echo $firstname."<br />".$lastname;?></div>
<br></body></html>
```

**profileLoad.php**

```
  <?php
         $firstname = "Arnab";
   $lastname = "Das";
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help :-

```
<?php

include("profileLoad.php");
// Variables $firstname  and  $lastname are available from this point

?>
<!-- Switch out of PHP into HTML -->
<div class = "profileText" style = "margin-top: 5%;"><?php echo "$firstname  $lastname"; ?></div> <br>
<!-- Some more HTML -->
```